bash/sed replace string of repeating string within a string
I have a file where each line represents data that may be encompassed with a string like "o o ".  I need to replace the string between the encompassing characters with another string.  The "internal" string is a pattern of two characters that may include an asterisk.
Here are some samples:
original string (OrigStrg):
"    o   o . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . o   o      "
I need to replace the internal string composed of the ". " pairs with another string that might look like:
". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . . "
The second string will be read in from a file and stored in a variable.
$ echo "$OrigStrg"    
   o   o . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . o   o  
$ echo "$NewLine"
            . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .

I am relatively new to regular expressions and so my ignorance will likely be evident.
Here are some of my attempts:
$ echo $OrigStrg|sed  's/\.\ \+//g'
o o o o

I know this will get rid of the inner string, but I also recognize this is handling each ". " separately.  This also gets rid of the double-spaces at the beginning and end of each line (which if possible, I'd like to retain).
These all seem to produce the same output:
$ echo "$OrigStrg" |sed -r "s/[. ]*/$NewLine/g"
$ echo "$OrigStrg" |sed -r "s/[. ]+/$NewLine/g"
$ echo "$OrigStrg" |sed -r "s/[\". \"]+/$NewLine/g" 
            . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .o            . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .o            . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .o            . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .o            . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .

These seem to get rid of the original "inner string" but then seems to put the replacement every where there is a double-space in the remaining string.
echo "$OrigStrg" |sed -r "s/[. ]*/$NewLine/"
            . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .o   o . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . o   o"

This attempt seems to insert the replacement string at the first double-space but then doesn't replace the original string (because the g at the end of the sed statement).
That seems to make sense when considering the "." as matching any single character.  Which seems to be what is happening in all of these examples.  I think I am close, but it is obvious I am not designating the two-character string sequence correctly.
What I am truly hoping for is this:
"    o   o . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . . o   o "
Any help is appreciated.

* in a replacement string shouldn't be any problem as * isn't a metacharacter in a replacement string for sed but & or \1 or / and maybe some others I haven't thought of would be. Can any of those or any other non-alphanumeric characters exist in your replacement string?

[. ] introduces a bracket expression that matches a dot or a space. [. ]+ matches even strings like ...., because you can't use a bracket expression to tell sed "one character must follow the other one". You can use parentheses for that, though:
#!/bin/bash
OrigStr='o   o . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . o   o'
NewStr='. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . * . . . .'

echo "$OrigStr" | sed -E "s/o( \.)+ o/o $NewStr o/"


Aah, thank you.  I believe that has led me in the right direction.

Per POSIX [...] is a bracket expression, not a character class. [:space:] is a character class and [[:space:]] is a bracket expression containing the character class [:space:] while [.] is a bracket expression containing the character .. I know there's some other terminology out there that refers to [...] as a character class and [:space:] as a POSIX character class and often people using that terminology refer to both as just "character class" but IMO that terminology and most descriptions using it are as clear as mud and best avoided in favor of the POSIX terminology.

@EdMorton: Any links? I'm coming from Perl, and there [...] is a character class, as is . - anything that matches a set of characters is.

@choroba per POSIX . inside a bracket expression is a "character list" that happens to be just 1 character. The part of the POSIX regular expressions spec that defines bracket expressions and what they can contain, including character classes (e.g. [:space:]),  character lists (e.g. abc), and character ranges (e.g. a-z) is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

I just googled for PCRE regexp terminology and found https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass which, among other things, defines . specifically as being it's very own character class. I had no idea til now that . was singled out like that in PCRE terminology, in POSIX . is just one of the regexp metachars along with *, ^, $, etc., nothing at all to do with character class terminology, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03 for BREs and https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03 for EREs.

So in PCRE terminology . is a character class but "[. ] introduces a character class that matches a dot or a space." so . and [.] are apparently both character classes.  Weird but OK I guess. Now [:space:] is also a character class so since I can write $string =~ /./ for the character class . I expect I must be able to write $string =~ /[:alpha:]/ for the character class [:alpha:] but no, I have to write $string =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ instead because the former would actually be a different character class, one containing the characters :, a, l, p, and h, i.e. [a:lph].

@EdMorton: Perl documentation calls [:...:] a "POSIX character class" :-)

@choroba right, I mentioned that in my first comment and then there's "bracketed character class" and "dot character class" and "backslash sequence character class". It's all these different uses of "character class" that are confusing, especially when most people and documentation drop the leading parts of the term and we're just left with "character class" for everything.

Even perldoc warns about that - Keep in mind, though, that often the term "character class" is used to mean just the bracketed form. Certainly, most Perl documentation does that.. After a lot of thought and experience I understand the differences now but I was confused for many years about what a "character class" actually was as that terminology is quite commonly used and makes things more confusing rather than clearer. I don't find any such confusion if I stick to POSIX terminology.

@EdMorton: I updated my answer accordingly.

Think it's worth leaving the comments in case anyone else finds the discussion on different terminology useful or should I just delete them? I'm absolutely fine deleting if you'd rather not have your answer cluttered up with them.

I find them useful, let's keep them.
